# how to create secured login page in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am developing an android application. i have created login page but it was not secured. i want to make this application as secured.

## My code:

```
  Button login;
  EditText username, password;
  DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
  static String code,loginSession;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernametxt);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordtxt);
    db.open();
    db.insertTest("password1");
    db.insertTest("password2");

    db.close();
    // login = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uname = username.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

            // ---get a title---
            db.open();


            Cursor c = db.getAllTest();
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {


                    if (uname.equals(c.getString(1))) {
                        code=c.getString(1);


                    } else {
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    // "Not Authenticated User..",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } while (c.moveToNext());


            }
            String pwd=code+"123";



             if (uname.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         "Please Enter User Name.",
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(pass.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         "Please Enter password.",
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else if(uname.equals(code) && pass.equals(pwd))
                {
                   Intent I=new Intent(loginPage.this, Test.class);
                   startActivity(I);

                }
            else if(uname!=(code)|| pass!=(pwd))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         "Not Authenticated User..",
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent I = new Intent(loginPage.this,loginPage.class);
                startActivity(I);
            }
            db.close();
```

Anyone help me to get a secured login page and let me know what are the secured login credentials needs to be followed?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood right, you wanna hide password characters while user type it.
In your layout put `android:inputType="textPassword"` to EditText control.

Comment: I already used same android:inputType="textPassword" in my xml file